# PHP Memory Leak

Tags: php, memory-leaks

Looking for a little help as Apache is complaining about this php code causing memory leaks.
Does anyone see anything out of the ordinary happening here? Specifically at $output .= ob_get_clean();

See code below;

```
function start_el( &$output, $comment, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
    $depth++;
    $GLOBALS['comment_depth'] = $depth;
    $GLOBALS['comment'] = $comment;

    if ( !empty( $args['callback'] ) ) {
        ob_start();
        call_user_func( $args['callback'], $comment, $args, $depth );
        $output .= ob_get_clean();
        return;
    }

    if ( ( 'pingback' == $comment->comment_type || 'trackback' == $comment->comment_type ) && $args['short_ping'] ) {
        ob_start();
        $this->ping( $comment, $depth, $args );
        $output .= ob_get_clean();
    } elseif ( 'html5' === $args['format'] ) {
        ob_start();
        $this->html5_comment( $comment, $depth, $args );
        $output .= ob_get_clean();
    } else {
        ob_start();
        $this->comment( $comment, $depth, $args );
        $output .= ob_get_clean();
    }
}
```

Comment: This code looks fine to me. What does `comment_email` look like? The `global $comment` is a little bit weird, why don't you just pass it in as a parameter?

Comment: Sorry I posted the wrong code, only had 3 coffees today. I have now posted the code that was causing "PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted"

Comment: I can't tell by just looking at this where the memory leaks is but you can see a construction that collects things: `$output`. Check the size of `$output` as it's running, see if that's the one that grows _more than you would expect_.

Comment: It's not possible to answer because in `call_user_func( $args['callback'], $comment, $args, $depth );` might happen anything. Same for `ping()`, `html5_comment()` and `comment()`. But my guess is (because of your `$depth`) that you have some very deep recursion.

Comment: BTW it helps a lot if you take a look with something like [xdebug](http://xdebug.org/).